# Java multi threaded web crawler is using only one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, threadpool, blockingqueue

I am Trying to write my first web-crawler in Java.

I thought I had it working, but when printing the thread details I see that only one thread is being used.

I initiated my working threads (10 threads.. but it seems like there is no switch).
Also, in the output (attached) it seems that url handling starts before all threads starting to run.

Can you please advise what to do or what I did wrong?

**Main class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {               
    String url ="https://jsoup.org/";
    Integer workers =10;
    Integer totalToScan=40;

    Set<String> visitedUrls = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> urlsToCrawlQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workers);

    Crawler crawler = new Crawler(visitedUrls,urlsToCrawlQueue,totalToScan,executor,workers);
    crawler.crawl(url);


    //crawler.getExecutor().shutdown();
    //try {
        //wait until all threads have ended
     //   crawler.getExecutor().awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    //} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     //   ex.printStackTrace();
    //}

    System.out.println("Crawling done. set size : " + crawler.getVisitedUrls().size());
    //printing the set
    int i =0;
    for(String x : crawler.getVisitedUrls())
    {
        System.out.println("Link #"+i+" --> " + x);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Crawler Class**

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;


public class Crawler {

    private Set<String> visitedUrls;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> urlsToCrawlQueue;
    private Integer maxSetSize;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Integer numOfWorkers;


    public Crawler(Set<String> visitedUrls, LinkedBlockingQueue<String> urlsToCrawlQueue, Integer maxSetSize, ExecutorService executor, Integer workers) {
        this.visitedUrls = visitedUrls;
        this.urlsToCrawlQueue = urlsToCrawlQueue;
        this.maxSetSize = maxSetSize;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.numOfWorkers = workers;
    }

    public void crawl(String url) {
        Init(url);
    }

    private void Init(String url) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWorkers; i++) {
            CrawlerWorker2 c = new CrawlerWorker2(this);
            executor.execute(c);
        }

        //Inserting the first url to queue. Expecting the threads to start pulling and working on it
        try {
            urlsToCrawlQueue.put(url);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   executor.shutdown();
        try {
            //wait until all threads have ended
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }


        }

    public Set<String> getVisitedUrls() {
        return visitedUrls;
    }

    public LinkedBlockingQueue<String> getUrlsToCrawlQueue() {
        return urlsToCrawlQueue;
    }

    public Integer getMaxSetSize() {
        return maxSetSize;
    }

    public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }

}
```

**Crawler Worker Class**

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CrawlerWorker2 implements Runnable {
    private Crawler crawler;

    public CrawlerWorker2(Crawler crawler) {
        this.crawler = crawler;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is starting to run");
        doWork();
    }

    private void doWork() {

        while (!crawler.getUrlsToCrawlQueue().isEmpty() && crawler.getVisitedUrls().size() < crawler.getMaxSetSize()) {
            //get url from queue
            String currUrl = null;
            try {
                currUrl = crawler.getUrlsToCrawlQueue().take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (currUrl == null || crawler.getVisitedUrls().contains(currUrl)) {
                System.out.println("Url is eather null or has been visited before. Skipping...");
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Handling url: " + currUrl );

            Connection con = Jsoup.connect(currUrl).timeout(1000 * 5);
            Connection.Response response = null;
            try {
                response = con.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error trying to reach url : " + currUrl);
                continue;
            }
            Document doc = null;
            if (response.statusCode() != 200) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                doc = con.get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error getting doc from url " + currUrl);
                continue;
            }

            crawler.getVisitedUrls().add(currUrl);
            System.out.println("Current Set size: " + crawler.getVisitedUrls().size());
            String title = doc.title();

            System.out.println("*********************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Worker Number: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", URL : " + currUrl + " title: " + title );
            System.out.println("*********************************************************************");


            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                String currentLink = link.attr("abs:href");
                try {
                    crawler.getUrlsToCrawlQueue().put(currentLink);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("INTERRUPT ERROR!!!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
 thread pool-1-thread-7 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-8 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-3 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-4 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-2 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-1 is starting to run
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/
thread pool-1-thread-5 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-9 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-6 is starting to run
thread pool-1-thread-10 is starting to run
Current Set size: 1
*********************************************************************
Worker Number: 18, URL : https://jsoup.org/ title: jsoup Java HTML Parser, with best of DOM, CSS, and jquery
*********************************************************************
Url is eather null or has been visited before. Skipping...
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/news/
Current Set size: 2
*********************************************************************
Worker Number: 18, URL : https://jsoup.org/news/ title: News: jsoup Java HTML parser
*********************************************************************
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/bugs
Current Set size: 3
*********************************************************************
Worker Number: 18, URL : https://jsoup.org/bugs title: Bugs: jsoup Java HTML parser
*********************************************************************
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/discussion
Current Set size: 4
*********************************************************************
Worker Number: 18, URL : https://jsoup.org/discussion title: Mailing lists: jsoup HTML parser
*********************************************************************
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/download
Current Set size: 5
*********************************************************************
Worker Number: 18, URL : https://jsoup.org/download title: Download the jsoup HTML parser library
*********************************************************************
Handling url: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/
```

Comment: Hint: there is directly a conceptual problem - why do Main and Crawler **both** now about the executor service? There should be one class that knows how to **crawl**; and there should be another class that owns an ExecutorService; and uses that to drive multiple crawlers.

Comment: @GhostCat can you please elaborate? The executor shutdown should be inside crawler? I can't understand what I am missing

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: This is java 8 version

Answer (score 0):

You only put a single url into the queue.

One thread gets that url, all the others quit because the queue is empty.

Comment: In my while loop ?